# Get the HTML as a string from a new Telerik RadHTMLChart on the backend

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, backend, radhtmlchart

I already have a function to convert an HTML page to an image and get its URI entirely on the backend before rendering the client.

I have 3 existing charts being created and data filled in on the back end.

I now need a way to convert or get the HTML content of a filled-in RadHTMLChart in order to render the Telerik HTML Chart as an image onto an email that will be sent out.

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation with several possible answers https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/htmlchart/how-to/export-to-pdf-on-the-server